# Avro model tries to register a new avro schema in schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, producer

I am trying to produce to a topic using axual
https://docs.axual.io/axual/2022.1/getting_started/producer/java/java-spring-producer.html

I managed to do all the setup and I have my avro schema registered in the platform but when I am trying to produce a message  apparently this

"Post /subjects/topicname/version is called "
which tries to register the avro schema again.

I found out that without of some sort of identifier  when producing the message schema registry will try to create all the time the schema and not use the one that it as already registered.

I am wondering if anyone had this problem